# Importing package in python error

Tags: linux, python-2.7, ubuntu, import, path

importing procedure in python -

```
utina@utinax55:~$ python
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/utina/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lal/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .lal import *
  File "/home/utina/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lal/lal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _lal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/utina/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lal/lal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_lal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libgsl.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>>> exit
```

libgsl.so.90 path is:

```
utina@utinax55:~$ locate libgsl
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.19
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.19.0.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.19
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgsl.so.19.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgslcblas.so.0.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libgsl-dbg
/usr/share/doc/libgsl-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgsl2
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/libgsl2
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgsl-dbg_2.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgsl-dev_2.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/libgsl2_2.1+dfsg-2_amd64.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgsl-dbg:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgsl-dbg:amd64.md5sums
```

My library path:

```
utina@utinax55:~$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

I tried to add this path to the `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run "`sudo ldconfig`" but these changes specified in previous posts did not change the import error in python.

I also specify that I installed libgsl dependency and also lal packages were installed using synaptic package manager.

Comment: The problem can be that python does the search in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/ , and thus considers the file ( libgsl.so.19) not found. That's one of the disadvantages of using a "multi-lib" setup.

Comment: Cheers, the question was solved by installing compat-libgsl2-19_2.1-2_amd64.deb