# Conflicts between 'gsl' dependencies in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python-import, gsl, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem with importing a module inside python, [adressed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098224/importing-package-in-python-error?noredirect=1#comment63631191_38098224), but it seemed that I need to install `libgsl.so.19` library, which is missing and there is no problem with the library path suggested in other posts. The thing is that this library is present in Ubuntu 16.04 in `libgsl2` package. My software requires `libgsl0ldbl` which interferes with `libgsl2`.

**Is there any way in Ubuntu 16 that `libgsl0ldbl` can contain `libgsl.so.19` library as well?**

cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way in Ubuntu 16 that libgsl0ldbl can contain
>   libgsl.so.19 library as well ?

No, but you can get a package `compat-libgsl2-19_2.1-2_amd64.deb` with only
`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/{ libgsl.so.19, libgsl.so.19.0.0 }`

Link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZXhrWENrOWt3QVU/view?usp=sharing

→ No conflicts with `libgsl0ldbl`.

---